# Initializing a 2D array of pointer of type double through double pointer with structure

Tags: c, pointers

I am doing something like following;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct
{
 double **arr;
}communication;

int main()
{
    int r = 3, c = 4, i, j, count;

    communication *comm;
    comm->arr = (double **)malloc(r * sizeof(double *));
    for (i=0; i<r; i++)
         comm->arr[i] = (double *)malloc(c * sizeof(double));

    count = 1;
    for (i = 0; i <  r; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
         comm->arr[i][j] = count*2.0;  
    for (i = 0; i <  r; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
         printf("%lf ", *(comm->arr[i]+j));


   return 0;
}
```

It is giving me seg fault error. Please tell me how can I define a 2D array through double-pointer method with structure just like I am trying to do in above code?

Comment: `comm` is a pointer. What does it point to?

Comment: `comm` is uninitialized. make it `communication comm;` instead as a pointer and access `comm.arr`

Comment: Don't cast the output of malloc

Comment: do something like this communication *comm = new communication;

Comment: Was your question asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60317881/initializing-a-2d-array-of-pointer-of-type-double-through-double-pointer resolved ? May be related

Comment: @SergeBallesta They are using a `typedef` so there's no need for the `struct` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You have not allocated memory to your `comm` variable.

Also `count` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

Either you do this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct
{
 double **arr;
}communication;

int main()
{
    int r = 3, c = 4, i, j, count;

    communication comm;
    comm.arr = malloc(r * sizeof(double *));
    for (i=0; i<r; i++)
         comm.arr[i] = malloc(c * sizeof(double));

    count = 1;
    for (i = 0; i <  r; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
         comm.arr[i][j] = count*2.0;  
    for (i = 0; i <  r; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
         printf("%lf ", *(comm.arr[i]+j));


   return 0;
}
```

Or this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct
{
 double **arr;
}communication;

int main()
{
    int r = 3, c = 4, i, j, count;

    communication *comm;
    comm = malloc(sizeof(communication));
    comm->arr = malloc(r * sizeof(double *));
    for (i=0; i<r; i++)
         comm->arr[i] = malloc(c * sizeof(double));

    count = 1;
    for (i = 0; i <  r; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
         comm->arr[i][j] = count*2.0;  
    for (i = 0; i <  r; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
         printf("%lf ", *(comm->arr[i]+j));


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not advise to use a C++ syntax for C code. You should at least warn future readers about that point...

Comment: Can you be clearer please?

Comment: You should not cast malloc in C...

Comment: You're right I'm gonna edit that

Comment: Thanks to all. It is working now. The memory allocation was the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate the memory for comm variable like the allocation of arr. Because comm is pointer, the defaut value may be NULL. So, you cannot point to the array arr inside of the struct communication.

Add this code below, your program will be work well:

```
 communication *comm = (communication *) malloc (sizeof(communication));
```

Comment: Nit: since it’s an `auto` variable, `comm` is not initialized with any particular value, `NULL` or otherwise.

Comment: I agree with you. Pointer doesn't have default value. I will correct the answer

Comment: Thanks to all for your replies. It is working now.